# How to display dialog before call powershell script?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to have a dialog box with 2 dates at sitecore 8.2 admin page, and call sitecore powershell script with parameters that came from dialog box ?
what is the best way to do it ?
it seems like SPEAK should be used here. Does any one has some examples ?

Comment: Can you have the dialog in the powershell script itself?

Comment: @adarsh yes as an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this snippet in your powershell script.

```
$dialog = Read-Variable -Parameters `
@{ Name = "Date1"; Title = "Date 1"; Editor="Date"}, `
@{ Name = "Date2"; Title = "Date 1";  Editor="Date"} `
-Description "Input Date." `
-Width 800 -Height 600 `
-Title "Date Input" `
-OkButtonName "Start" `
-CancelButtonName "Cancel"

if($dialog -ne "ok"){exit}

Write-Host $Date1;
```

This will create the dialog for inputting the different dates that you need.